# Mysql table to csv

Tags: mysql

I try to create `csv` file in order to use it in excel or liberoffice calc. But I have this problem.

```
mysql> SELECT *
    FROM formtable
    INTO OUTFILE "/tmp/try.csv"
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ESCAPED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";
```

If I use this command everything works smoothly. But on the server side, I don't think I have tmp folder like tmp folder in linux. As a result, I try to give specific path below

```
mysql> SELECT *
    FROM formtable
    INTO OUTFILE "/var/www/try.csv"
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ESCAPED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";
```

And it gives

```
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/var/www/try.csv' (Errcode: 13)
```

Same error exist if I give path as `/home/blah/try.csv`. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Are you on windows/dos machine?
If that is the case the path should be relative to C:/

Comment: What machine is the server on? If linux, do the user/paths have sufficient write permissions? If the server is anything but linux, you will  need to change the pathnames.

Comment: mysql probably doesn't have write permission to your home directory or /var/www/

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;    
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class WriteCSV {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select id_movie, movie_name from movies");
            String csv = "E:\\dummyFolder\\output2.csv";
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));
            List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            while (rs.next())
            {
                data.add(new String[] { rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2) });
            }
            writer.writeAll(data);
            System.out.println("CSV written successfully.");
            writer.close();

        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

you need to add the opencsv-2.3.jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadopencsv23jar.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You should check the permissions.
`ls -l /your/path`.

Please note that not your user should have permissions to write to selected folder, but `mysql` user. Your should check owner, group, "others" permissions.

Usually you can create file in `/tmp` folder.